# Pass data from for loop in view back to controller

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I am creating a form in a for loop in Razor.

```
@model SignAPI.ViewModels.ChannelManagerViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ChannelManager", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerNames, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerNameSelected, Model.CustomerNames, "Select", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control form-control-sm", @id = "CustomerDdl", @data_val = false })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerNameSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Devices, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DeviceSelected, Model.Devices, "Select", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "form -control form-control-sm", @id = "DeviceDdl", @data_val = false })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DeviceSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "ChannelManager", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table class="table table-striped" style="font-size:small;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Channel Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        UOM's'
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Channel UOM
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Calculated
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @{  var channelNames = Model.ChannelNames.Select(x => x.ChannelName).OrderByDescending(x => Model.ChannelName).ToList();
                    for (int count = 0; count < channelNames.Count(); count++)
                    {
                        var channel = channelNames[count];

                        var ddlId = ("ddlId" + count).ToString();
                        var txtBoxId = ("txtBoxId" + count).ToString();
                        <tr>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CustomerNameSelected)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DeviceSelected)
                            <td>
                                @Html.Label(channel)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UomSelected, Model.Uom, "Select", new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", @id = @ddlId, @data_val = false })
                                <script type="text/javascript">

                                        $('#@ddlId').change(function () {
                                            $('#@txtBoxId').val($(this).val());
                                        });
                                </script>
                            </td>
                            <td>                                
                                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ChannelDataToSave, Model.UomSelected, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = @txtBoxId, @class = "form-control form-control-sm" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ChannelType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Calculated)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</div>
```

I want to pass all of the data created in the second form back to my `Action` using the ViewModel:

```
 public class ChannelManagerViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Select a customer")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerNames { get; set; }
        public string CustomerNameSelected { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Select a device")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Devices { get; set; }
        public string DeviceSelected { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Channel Name")]
        public string ChannelName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Channel Type")]
        public string ChannelType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Calculated")]
        public bool Calculated { get; set; }

        public int ChannelCount { get; set; }

        public List<ChannelManagerModel> ChannelNames { get; set; }
        public List<ChannelManagerViewModel> ChannelDataToSave { get; set; }

        private List<string> UomList {
            get
            {
                var l = new List<string>();
                l.Add("Electricity");
                l.Add("Gas");
                l.Add("Water");
                l.Add("Heat");
                l.Add("kWh");
                l.Add("Wh");
                l.Add("kVarh");
                l.Add("Wh");
                l.Add("Volts 1");
                l.Add("Volts 2");
                l.Add("Volts 3");
                l.Add("Current 1");
                l.Add("Current 2");
                l.Add("Current 3");
                l.Add("Hz");
                l.Add("Litres");
                l.Add("Cubic Metres");
                l.Add("Cubic Feet");

                return l;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Uom {

            get {

                List<SelectListItem> sl = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (var item in UomList)
                {
                    sl.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item, Value = item });
                };

                return sl;
            }

            set { }
        }
        public string UomSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to then save the data.

I have tried a number of things including using a partial view, but that doesn't work. I have also tried adding the loop index

```
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x[count].ChannelDataToSave, Model.UomSelected, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = @txtBoxId, @class = "form-control form-control-sm" } })
```

but this just tells me `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ChannelManagerViewModel'`

I was hoping that the form would create a `List<ChannelManagerViewModel>` to pass back to the `Action`

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveData(ChannelManagerViewModel vm)
        {
            //Do some stuff
            return View(vm);            
        }
```

All it passes back is a null viewmodel.

Can you advise what is wrong with this?

The expected outcome is that when the form is created in the for loop, it creates a List to pass back to the `Action` in the `Controller`. Currently it doesn't...

TIA

Comment: Are you looking for [Model Binding To A List](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)?

Comment: Ideally yes. but I am thinking of creating it in JQuery. I would like to retain binding to the model if possible. I'm just going around in circles at the moment.

Comment: I thank that link is what I am looking for.